# Enforcing a particular jar version during build

Tags: java, ant, ivy

In our project we are using Ant Build to generate ear. While Building we are using ivy.xml file in which we are mentioning all the required jars of the project.

Issue: I need junit-4.10.jar to build my junit but while running i am getting "VM Fork Error. Exiting Abnormally" I analyzed and found that some of my  other dependent jars that i mention in ivy file is internally using junit-3.8.jar so as we have 2 version of same jar it is not able to resolve what to use at runtime.

what should I do if I want to enforce to use junit-4.10 version jar over 3.8 version.